# Form authentication password verification issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008

I'm working on an intranet and am using form authentication.

I've just added a feature that creates an account whenever I create a new Employee (as if Registering was through the Employee panel).

```
  if (_service.Create(objEmployee))
  {
      WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(objEmployee.Login, objEmployee.Password); // Creates the account as we create the Employee
      return new RedirectResult(Url.Action("Index"));
  }
```

But I wish to understand and change the following :

Whenever I log in it seems to check a specific table created by the form authentication, what table is it and how may I change it so that it checks my Employee one (that contains my password)?

Comment: You need to use custom forms authentication, here is good tutorial for achieve that: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/578374/AplusBeginner-splusTutorialplusonplusCustomplusF, read from Custom Forms Authentication

Comment: The table used in 2013 is aspnetusers

Comment: I see, but I can't seem to find it among the other tables (that were created with the form auth. such as dbo.UserProfile)